# React Native : Native base contentContainerStyle attribute in content component doesn't work while screen rotation

Tags: android, react-native, native-base

I'm using :

```
<Content contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
```

**1. In portrait view UI looks ok.**

**2. But in landscape view I can't  scroll UI.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Content extends scrollview. Flex won't work with scrollviews.

Comment: Any other way do vertical align with scroll view in react native ? @SagarKhatri

Answer (score 0):

I had this:

```
<Content padder  contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
  <Form>
    <Label style={styles.labelText}>Seleccione Cortadores</Label>
    .
    .
    .
  </Form>
</Content>
```

It worked when i removed the contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}